# Perl + oracle dba

Tags: oracle, perl, database-administration

I'm newbie in perl and trying to list out all oracle schema tables which were created yesterday i.e. (sysdate - 1)

trying to achieve above via perl script and run against oracle database.

Q:
1. List all recently created oracle table using perl script
2. columns in result (Schema, table_name, created datetime)
3. Only provide output if any new table was created orelse no email via scheduler

e.g.

```
select schema, table_name, created
from dba_objects
where created = sysdate - 1
and object_type = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: its not `schema` it should be `owner` and `object_name` instead of `table_name`.

Answer (score 0):

A `date` in Oracle, by definition, includes both a day component and a time to the second.  Even if your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` only specifies that you want to display the day component, the time is still there.  And the time is almost certainly causing your query to return no rows. `sysdate - 1` returns exactly 24 hours ago.  So if today is January 14, 2013 at 13:41:35, `sysdate - 1` returns January 13, 2013 at 13:41:35.  Your query will only return tables that were created at that exact second.

`trunc(sysdate)` returns today at midnight and `trunc(sysdate - 1)` returns yesterday at midnight.  So, most likely, you want something like

```
SELECT owner, object_name
  FROM dba_objects
 WHERE created >= trunc(sysdate - 1)
   AND created < trunc(sysdate)
   AND object_type = 'TABLE'
```

Since `dba_objects` doesn't have columns `schema` or `table_name`, I'm assuming that you mean `owner` and `object_name`.

Comment: Thank you justin for quick response... yes you were right in assuming owner and object_name, this always tricks me via query so have to do desc before I write sql on dba_objects.  My problem is with creating perl script since don't have any clue of where to start. Working on that...